# Console.ReadLine() function is not working

Tags: c#, function

See the program below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace FileOperation1
{
    class FileMain
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileMain fm = new FileMain();
            char ch = fm.Menu();
            while (ch != '0')
            {
                switch (ch)
                { 
                    case '0':
                        break;
                    case '1':
                        //Console.WriteLine("This featute is not implemented till now.");
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        Console.Write("Enter the name of the file: ");
                        String FileName = Console.ReadLine();// ReadLine() method is not workin here
                        FileOperation Fo=new FileOperation();
                        Console.WriteLine("\n" + Fo.FileRead(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        //Console.WriteLine("This featute is not implemented till now.");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid choice. Enter again.");
                        break;
                }
                ch = fm.Menu();
            }
        }
        private char Menu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t***File Operations***");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Create a new file");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Open a file");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Edit an existing file");
            Console.WriteLine("0. Exit");
            Console.Write("\nEnter your choice: "); 
            char ch = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read()); //Read() Method is not working properly
            return ch;
        }
    }
    public class FileOperation
    {
        private String FileRead(FileStream Fs)
        {
            StreamReader Sr = new StreamReader(Fs);
            Sr.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            String str = ""+(Char)Sr.Read();
            String ret = "";
            while (!Sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                ret += str;
                str = ""+(Char)Sr.Read();
            }
            Sr.Close();
            return ret;
        }
        public String FileRead(String FileName, FileMode Fm, FileAccess Fa)
        {
            FileOperation Fo = new FileOperation();
            FileStream Fs = new FileStream(FileName, Fm, Fa);
            String ret = Fo.FileRead(Fs);
            Fs.Close();
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2005. Here `Console.ReadLine()` and `Console.Read()` functions are not working properly for this program. Why?

Comment: "not working properly" could mean anything... what's actually happening, and what were you expecting to happen? Note that `Console.Read()` won't return (IIRC) until the user hits return anyway.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Console.Read() and Console.ReadLine() automatically returns empty value(output does not gives me a chance to hit enter.

Comment: @chanchal1987: It will only do that if you've *previously* pressed enter, e.g. as part of an earlier call to `Console.Read()`

Comment: @Jon Skeet:
    Console.Write("\nEnter your choice: "); 
    char ch = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
If I pressed '1' or '3' and press 'Enter' one time, Menu automatically displayed 3 times (Message: 'Invalid choice. Enter again.'). And if I pressed '2' it automatically goes to the 'FileRead()' function and an error message is showing: "ArgumentException was unhandled: Empty path name is not legal."

Comment: @chanchal1987: Yes, because it's only reading "1" from the first call to `Console.Read()`, despite waiting for you to hit return. The `Console.ReadLine()` will immediately read an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `Console.Read()` methods with `Console.ReadLine()`. See more about [`Console.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx) and [`Console.ReadLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx) method from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/default.aspx). Edited program is given below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace FileOperation1
{
    class FileMain
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileMain fm = new FileMain();
            char ch = fm.Menu();
            while (ch != '0')
            {
                switch (ch)
                {
                    case '0':
                        break;
                    case '1':
                        //Console.WriteLine("This featute is not implemented till now.");
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        Console.Write("Enter the name of the file: ");
                        String FileName = Console.ReadLine();// ReadLine() method is not workin here
                        FileOperation Fo = new FileOperation();
                        Console.WriteLine("\n" + Fo.FileRead(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        //Console.WriteLine("This featute is not implemented till now.");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid choice. Enter again.");
                        break;
                }
                ch = fm.Menu();
            }
        }
        private char Menu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t***File Operations***");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Create a new file");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Open a file");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Edit an existing file");
            Console.WriteLine("0. Exit");
            Console.Write("\nEnter your choice: ");
            char ch = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine()); //Read() Method is not working properly
            return ch;
        }
    }
    public class FileOperation
    {
        private String FileRead(FileStream Fs)
        {
            StreamReader Sr = new StreamReader(Fs);
            Sr.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            String str = "" + (Char)Sr.Read();
            String ret = "";
            while (!Sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                ret += str;
                str = "" + (Char)Sr.Read();
            }
            Sr.Close();
            return ret;
        }
        public String FileRead(String FileName, FileMode Fm, FileAccess Fa)
        {
            FileOperation Fo = new FileOperation();
            FileStream Fs = new FileStream(FileName, Fm, Fa);
            String ret = Fo.FileRead(Fs);
            Fs.Close();
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You may want to try [Console.ReadKey(true)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3h8xffw.aspx) , this waits for the next key press then continues, the function returns a [ConsoleKeyInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo.aspx). You could use a switch statement when referring to the [ConsoleKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekey.aspx) value in the Key property:

```
    var c = Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(c.Key.ToString());

    // Prints
    //a
    //A

    switch(c.Key)
    {
        case ConsoleKey.D0:
            //User entered 0
            Console.WriteLine("Exiting...");
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.D1:
            //User entered 1
            Console.WriteLine("You chose to create a new file!");
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.D2:
            //User entered 2
            Console.WriteLine("You chose to open a file!");
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.D3:
            //User entered 3
            Console.WriteLine("You chose to edit an existing file!");
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("No response for that key");
            break;
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: But what is the problem with my program?